# Why the scala compiler encoding different names with/without inner class’s accessing?

Tags: scala, encoding

Given the following scala 3.x codes (I also asked in [users.scala-lang.org](https://users.scala-lang.org/t/the-scala-compiler-encoding-different-names-with-without-inner-classs-accessing/9638/3)):

```
object NameEncodingTest:
    class HasInner:
        private val x: Int = 0
        private val y: Int = 0

        def getX: Int = x
        def getY: Int = y

        class Inner:
            val inner: Int = y
```

Decompile the compiled class file to java:

```
/*
 * Decompiled with CFR 0.152.
 */
public static class NameEncodingTest.HasInner {
    private final int x;
    public final int NameEncodingTest$HasInner$$y;

    public NameEncodingTest.HasInner() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.NameEncodingTest$HasInner$$y = 0;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return this.NameEncodingTest$HasInner$$y;
    }
}
```

**As a comparison, the class file of javac has the same naming schemas**:

```
// HasInner.java
public class HasInner {
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;

    class Inner {
        final int inner = y;
    }
}
```

Which compiles to:

```
/*
 * Decompiled with CFR 0.152.
 */
public class HasInner {
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;

    class Inner {
        final int inner;

        Inner() {
            this.inner = HasInner.this.y;
        }
    }
}
```

I am very curious that:

- Why the fields x and y was using different schemas to encode?
- Why the field y is changed to public (is not it private ok too)?
- **Is not the simple name schema enough for both cases** (just as the javac) ?

Comment: https://users.scala-lang.org/t/the-scala-compiler-encoding-different-names-with-without-inner-classs-accessing/9638/